# Directories listed in /etc/synthetic.conf not accessible via the link

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina

Background:  `Catalina` removes access from the root filesystem. We can not create directories there even as `sudo` and even when disabling `SIP`.  There appears to be a kind of workaround by using `/etc/synthetic.conf`.

Here is the contents of my `/etc/synthetic.conf`

```
  data    /Users/steve/data
  git     /Users/steve/git
  shared  /Users/steve/shared
```

I have created those directories under my home directory and rebooted.

```
$ls -lrta /Users/steve/data /Users/steve/shared
/Users/steve/data:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 steve  staff    64 Apr 11 19:02 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 250 steve  staff  8000 Apr 13 11:29 ..

/Users/steve/shared:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 steve  staff    64 Apr 11 19:02 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 250 steve  staff  8000 Apr 13 11:29 ..

$ls -lrta /Users/steve/data /Users/steve/gut
/Users/steve/git:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 steve  staff    64 Apr 11 19:02 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 250 steve  staff  8000 Apr 13 11:29 ..
```

So those directories *do* exist ..

But then using the link from /etc/synthetic.conf does not work the way I had expected:

```
(base) 11:29:14/git $ls -lrta /data
ls: /data: No such file or directory
```

How is that association/link supposed to be used?

**Update** Permissions for `/etc/synthetic.conf` are

```
(base) 12:27:46/~ $ll /etc/synthetic.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  77 Apr 11 19.:54 /etc/synthetic.conf
```

Comment: Full command: `echo -e 'data\tUsers/steve/data\ngit\tUsers/steve/git\nshared\tUsers/steve/shared\n' | sudo tee -a /etc/synthetic.conf` to avoid vim ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First make sure that you have created the file with the correct file permissions:

```
  Owner: root 
  Group: wheel

  Owner: read+write
  Group: read
  Everyone: read
```

Make sure that the two columns in your file are seperated by tab characters, and not just spaces.

Additionally the names of your existing folders probably need to be written without the leading slash. At least this is how the man page specifies it, and it is the only way I have tried it - it might work with a leading slash though.

I.e. you need to write `Users/steve/data` instead of `/Users/steve/data`.

Next ensure that you have rebooted your system after modifying or creating `synthetic.conf`. The links are only available after a reboot.

Comment: I did all these afaict.  I will double check that the tab did not get replaced by spaces at some point.  Update: it appears the tab may have been replaced with spaces by one of the editors automatically at some point. I'm fixing now

Answer (score 3):

The linked folders in synthetic.conf **must not** contain leading slashes (and the two columns must be seperated by tab characters as jksoegaard mentioned already):

Modify /etc/synthetic.conf to

```
data    Users/steve/data
git     Users/steve/git
shared  Users/steve/shared
```

and reboot!

Comment: Thanks i missed that.  I can't get vim to stop replacing tab with space.. gimme couple mins..

Comment: I turned off  `expandtab` but can not get vi to stop the conversion for the life of me.  Trying your command line now.  I awarded to @jksoegaard simply due to his geting there a tad sooner: but both of you helped equally

Comment: i'm going to ask a separate question about this `vim` nonsense

Comment: .all working now thx . i had upvoted couple hours back but can only award to one person. It was bit of a coin flip.

Comment: The bolded word appears to be misspelled and doesn't make sense. Did you mean "must not"?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-: It appears to be a phonetic mis-spelling of "mustn't". [I submitted an edit for review](https://apple.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/32784).

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how to create the symbolic link `/All fonts` which points to the folder `/Users/jamesoconnor/All fonts`. Note: Any previous entries in the `/etc/synthetic.conf` file will be removed. This answer was tested using macOS Catalina version 10.15.7.

1. Enter the command below to remove any existing `/etc/synthetic.conf` file.

   ```
   sudo rm -f /etc/synthetic.conf
   ```
2. Enter the command below to create the `/etc/synthetic.conf` file.

   ```
   echo -e "All fonts\tUsers/jamesoconnor/All fonts" | sudo tee /etc/synthetic.conf
   ```
3. This step assumes the current user's home folder is `/Users/jamesoconnor`. Enter the command below to create the folder `/User/jamesoconnor/All fonts`. Note that if this folder already exists, the command will do nothing.

   ```
   mkdir -p "/Users/jamesoconnor/All fonts"
   ```
4. Restart the Mac.
5. Verify the existence of the pertinent files and folders by entering the commands given below.

   ```
   ls -lOe@d /etc/synthetic.conf
   cat /etc/synthetic.conf
   vis -wc /etc/synthetic.conf; echo
   ls -lOe@d "/All fonts"
   ls -lOe@d "/Users/jamesoconnor/All fonts"
   ```

Below is sample output from entering the commands given in steps 1 through 3.

```
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ % sudo rm -f /etc/synthetic.conf
Password:
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ % echo -e "All fonts\tUsers/jamesoconnor/All fonts" | sudo tee /etc/synthetic.conf
All fonts   Users/jamesoconnor/All fonts
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ % mkdir -p "/Users/jamesoconnor/All fonts"
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ %
```

Below is sample output from entering the commands given in step 5.

```
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ % ls -lOe@d /etc/synthetic.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  - 39 Sep 23 20:17 /etc/synthetic.conf
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ % cat /etc/synthetic.conf      
All fonts   Users/jamesoconnor/All fonts
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ % vis -wc /etc/synthetic.conf; echo
All\sfonts\tUsers/jamesoconnor/All\sfonts\n
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ % ls -lOe@d "/All fonts"
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  - 28 Sep 23 14:23 /All fonts -> Users/jamesoconnor/All fonts
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ % ls -lOe@d "/Users/jamesoconnor/All fonts"
drwxr-xr-x  2 jamesoconnor  staff  - 64 Sep 23 19:57 /Users/jamesoconnor/All fonts
jamesoconnor@dmas-Mac ~ %
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Trun off vim `expandtab` configuration, or rename vim configuration file `vimrc`.
2. Confirm the two columns are seperated by **tab** instead of space.
3. Remove the leading slashes from the 2nd column.